# Is $\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}$ a subset of $\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic

I reached an unexpected conclusion with the answer I got from the exercise below. From the expression's valuation, it seems to be true. I distrust my answer (I am still so painfully clumsy with these concepts) but, I don't yet know if and where I miscalculated.
Your always appreciated insight is welcome. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly note that $\Bbb{Q}\cap\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Q}$. That is to say, that $\Bbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\Bbb{R}$. From this it follows directly that $\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}$, the set of all elements of $\Bbb{Q}$ that are not in $\Bbb{R}$, is empty. So indeed $\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}=\varnothing$, and indeed the empty set is a subset of *every* set, in particular of $\Bbb{Z}$.

A minor remark on your notes; you write
$$\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}\quad =\quad(\Bbb{Q}\cap\bar{\Bbb{R}})\subseteq\Bbb{Z},$$
which doesn't make sense semantically. What you (probably) mean is that the two logical statements are equivalent. You can express this by writing
$$\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad(\Bbb{Q}\cap\bar{\Bbb{R}})\subseteq\Bbb{Z}.$$
The same goes for the chain of 'equalities' (actually equivalences) that follows. If you prefer to write a chain of equalities, you could write
$$\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Q}\cap\bar{\Bbb{R}}=\ldots=\varnothing,$$
and then note that $\varnothing\subseteq\Bbb{Z}$, and conclude that $\Bbb{Q}\backslash\Bbb{R}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you kindly